# Цикл while с двойным условием в python

Tags: python, циклы, while

Собственно проблема следующая: когда оставляешь в цикле только одно из условий, все работает без нареканий. Как только добавляешь второе условие, они оба начинают просто игнорироваться, хотя должны соблюдаться вместе. И в тело цикла просто не заходит при любом веденном числе

```
number = int(input('Введите число: '))

while number >= 10 and number <= 0:
    print('Не верно. Число должно быть от 1 до 9 включительно')
    number = int(input('Введите число: '))

number = number ** 2
print(number)
```

Comment: А как число может быть одновременно больше 10 и меньше 0?

Comment: Я просто не нашел другого способа как заставить ввести число от 1 до 9 включительно) Как одновременно исключить ноль, отрицательные числа, 10 и то что больше 10

Answer (score 4):

Очевидно, что число не может быть одновременно больше 10 и меньше 0. Замените `and` на `or`.

Предположим, что number равно 15. Тогда имеем следующее:

- number >= 10 - True
- number <= 0 - False

По [таблице истинности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) True AND False дает False, поэтому в цикл не попадает. 
То же самое, если число меньше 0.

А вот True OR False как раз дает True и выполнение заходит в цикл.

Comment: Все стало работать) Но честно говоря непонятно почему это работает если именно and делает так, чтобы соблюдались оба условия, а or одно из них

Comment: Именно потому так и работает. Если and, что number должно быть **больше 10 И ОДНОВРЕМЕННО меньше 0**. А если or, то больше 10 ИЛИ меньше 0.

Comment: я немного дополнил объяснение.

Answer (score 2):

Для большей понятности можно обратить условие, написав отрицание через `not` и взяв в скобки верное условие:

```
while not (number >= 1 and number <= 9):
    print('Не верно. Число должно быть от 1 до 9 включительно')
    number = int(input('Введите число: '))
```

Т.е. цикл будет выполняться, пока не выполнилось искомое условие, что число "от 1 до 9 включительно".

P.S. Есть три отрезка, которым может принадлежать проверяемое число:

- Числа < 1
- Числа от 1 до 9
- Числа > 9

Число может принадлежать одному из этих отрезков. Когда вы проверяете число на принадлежность отрезку [1,9] вы можете писать условия через `и/and`, потому что это **один отрезок** но когда вы проверяете, что число находится **в одном из двух разных** отрезков (меньше 1 либо, больше 9) вы не можете использовать `и/and`, а только `или/or` - это два **разных** отрезка, число не может принадлежать сразу и тому отрезку и другому.